# How to abbreviate class name inside its own definition?

Tags: c++, class, typedef, using

How can I create an alias for a lengthy class name inside the definition of this class? I don't want it to be accessible outside the class definition. I can't get it to work with either `typedef` or `using`.

It's a class template in my case.

```
template<typename T>
class detailed_class_name{

typedef detailed_class_name<T> foo; // either one 
using foo = detailed_class_name<T>; // of these 

public:
    foo(); // Error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'foo' with no type. 
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `foo();`should be the declaration of the constructor? You can't.

Comment: You can't rename the constructors or destructor. If the name of the class is bothering you, perhaps it deserves a renaming?

Comment: The class name is chosed to be descriptive which makes it very long in this case (a type of a linked list with very special features). I just wanted the class declaration to be as neat and clear as possible, without the long class name. I figured that a comment establishing what the class is about would allow me to abbreviate its name for the rest of its declaration.
I suspected that using `ll` instead of `linked_list_with_special_invariances_for_a_number_of_special_cases` would be appreciated by others using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. A constructor's *id-expression*, i.e. the name of the constructor in a class definition is according to [[class.ctor]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#1.1) (emphasis mine):

> - in a *member-declaration* that belongs to the *member-specification* of a class but is not a friend declaration, **the *id-expression* is the injected-class-name of the immediately-enclosing class**;

And what is an injected-class-name? According to [[class]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#2)

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen. **The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name**. [...]

And so the injected-class-name is the name of the class itself, and cannot be an alias.

This is further reinforced by this sentence in [[class.ctor]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#1.sentence-4):

> The *class-name* shall not be a *typedef-name*.

Consider renaming the class if you don't even want to write a constructor because the name is too convoluted.

Comment: I couldn't have hoped for a clearer answer. Thank you, sir.

Comment: @Jersey I mean, if it is really that bad, you can also use a macro, but I really wouldn't recommend *that*.